# Phase-vocoder normalization for different speed factors

Tags: audio, real-time, normalization

**Question in short:** How can I normalize audio from a block-based phase-vocoder system without knowing the global minimum and maximum during runtime?

**Longer version:**

Hey! I am very new to DSP and need some help with figuring out an issue that I have (or understanding the math behind it). I am using the [RubberBand](https://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/technical.html) audio time-stretching/pitch-shifting C++ library and stream audio to and from it. But, it results in differently-normalized audio.

What I mean with this, is that I stream sample-blocks that are normalized within `[-1, 1]`. However, it returns audio within some range `[x, y]` where `x` and `y` are seemingly quite random, except for a speed-factor of 100%, where it stays perfectly normalized. My question is: is there some way I can know `x` and `y`, without needing to stream all my audio beforehand (for real-time usage)? A graph of the minimum and maximum of the audio is given below, so you can see what I mean:

[image: minima and maxima of audio for different speed factors]

I hope to find out what the mathematical source of this is. I have read online and believed that phase vocoders are supposed to keep audio normalized as long as the input was normalized?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can’t know the loudness of future stream. But a dynamic range controller would help. Try to use DRC to normalize your output stream.

Comment: @ZRHan thanks! I was looking at some other normalization and controllers but they all sounded very weird. A DRC is exactly what I need.